# angular ui views does not scroll to bottom

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i am struggling with angular ui router.

it renders a view with a ng-repeat table correctly, but a detail view with ng-repeat is not.

the template loads, DOM is rendered and ng-repeat kicks in... content is shown but i cant scroll down to see the whole content

```
<ui-view></ui-view>

$stateProvider
.state('tickets', {
    url: '/tickets',
    templateUrl: '/assets/html/tickets.html',
    controller: 'ticketController'
})
.state('dashboard', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: '/assets/html/dashboard.html',
    controller: 'dashboardController'
})
.state('ticketDetail', {
    url: '/tickets/:id',
    templateUrl: '/assets/html/ticketDetail.html',
    controller: 'ticketDetailController'
});
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('dashboard');
```

The state tickets loads a list of tickets as mentioned and the state ticketDetail loads a detail view of a ticket, here if content is loaded from backend i cant scroll anymore...

it is very disappointing, when working with angular ui-router and this comes up!

I would be very happy for some solutions!

The Template i want to load:

```
<div class="container" style="top: 75px;">
<div class="columns">
<div class="column col-2"></div>
<div class="column col-8">
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
        <a ui-sref="tickets">
            Tickets
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
        <a href="#">
            {{thisTicket.id}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="divider"></div>
<div ng-if="isLoading == true" class="loading"></div>
<div ng-if="isLoading == false">
<div class="columns">
    <div class="column"><h6>Titel:</h6>{{thisTicket.title}}</div>
    <div class="column"><h6>Priority:</h6>{{thisTicket.priority}}</div>
    <div class="column"><h6>Status:</h6><span class="label label-primary">{{thisTicket.status}}</span></div>
    <div class="column"><h6>Type:</h6>{{thisTicket.type}}</div>
    <div class="column"><h6>Assignee:</h6>{{thisTicket.assignee}}</div>
    <div class="column"><h6>Owner:</h6>{{thisTicket.owner}}</div>
</div>
<br>
</div>
<div class="divider"></div>
<ul class="tab tab-block">
    <li class="tab-item active">
        <a >
            Conversation
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab-item">
        <a >
            Attachements
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab-item">
        <a >
            Images
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab-item">
        <a >
            Connect
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div scroll-glue>
    <!-- Content here will be "scroll-glued". -->
    <blockquote ng-repeat="comment in thisTicket.comments">
        <p ng-bind-html="comment.text"></p>
        <cite>
            <div class="chip-sm">
                <img src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/callofduty/images/c/c5/GHOSTS.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130501101925" class="avatar" />
                <span class="chip-name">{{comment.owner}} at {{comment.createDate}}</span>
            </div>
        </cite>
    </blockquote>
</div>
    <!-- form textarea control -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-label" for="input-example-3">Message</label>
        <text-angular ng-model="comment" style="" ta-toolbar="[['bold','italics','underline','strikeThrough'],['pre','quote'],['ul','ol']]"></text-angular>
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-block" ng-click="addComment(comment)">Absenden</button>
    </div>
    </div>
<div class="column col-2"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @hva.narole
thx for improving!

Comment: This is not enough info. I understand the template loads correctly but what is the content of the template? perhaps if you show us some more code we can help you better.

Comment: Hi @MuliYulzary it is difficulty to explain this behavior with code - maybe a screenshot will help you to understand?

Comment: A screenshot will be fine

Comment: @MuliYulzary here you go: [link](https://postimg.org/image/i8prrom87/)

Comment: Are there any styles applied to this template? can I have a look at the template?

Comment: i will attach the template in original post

Comment: @MuliYulzary done :)

Comment: all in the scroll-glue section will be act like a chat - the bottom is always visible.

Comment: look here: http://plnkr.co/edit/wxTyp7PpyxJOHSlUumVC?p=preview

Comment: @MuliYulzary i solved the problem by myself it was a stupid mistake by using a library without knowing whats going on.

"snap-content" is needed to initalize any content div...